# Reading from file, strange ending

Tags: c++, printf, ifstream

I've found a snippet of code that gives the size of a text file:

```
ifstream file("xmlfile.xml",ios::in);
//get size
file.seekg (0, ios::end);
int length = file.tellg();
file.seekg (0, ios::beg);

// allocate memory:
char* buffer = new char [length];

// read data as a block:
file.read (buffer,length);
file.close();
buffer[length-1] = '\0';
printf("%s",buffer);
```

the thing is that with a small xml file that i would like to read, reads it perfectly, but leaves many '=' signs at the end, as i found out they equal to the number of CR's in the file. Switching the EOL to Unix solved the problem, but why is there a problem with printing in the Windows EOLs?

Sample xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>




(EOL)
```

And what the printf prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>





══════
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues.

Using `seek` and `tell` to get the file size will tell you how many bytes are in the file.  A Windows EOL on disc is two bytes.  However when you read it with `read` on a file that was opened in text mode, the EOL becomes one byte in memory.  You can fix this by opening the file in binary mode like this:

```
ifstream file("xmlfile.xml",ios::in | ios::binary);
```

The other problem is that if you want to treat the contents of the file as a null terminated string, you need to allocate extra space for the NULL terminator.  As it stands, you are overwriting the last byte of the file with NULL.  You should do this:

```
char* buffer = new char [length+1];
```

and

```
buffer[length] = '\0';
```

Comment: i have terminated the string with a \0, just not at length, but length-1

Answer (score 3):

The problem arises because Windows uses Carriage Return + Line Feed characters at the end of each line, whereas Linux only uses one of those.

Your ifstream opens in text mode. It returns the absolute size of the text file, but then you instruct it to read that many *text* characters. It seems to be discarding the extra character that Windows doesn't use automatically, and you're ending up reading past the end of the file.

To correct this, .gcount() may be used to obtain the number of characters read.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what's happening, `tellg` tells you the position *in bytes*, but during the read the Windows line endings are converted to plain `'\n`'; because of this, the position referred by `buffer[length]` is after the "real" ending of the number of "missing" CRs.

To avoid this problem, after reading the file call `file.gcount()` to obtain the number of characters read during the last read, and use it as the position where to terminate the buffer.

Comment: solves the problem, but also why does it leave '=' all the way? its not some strange symbols that were not overwritten

Comment: The `=` signs happened to be the "strange symbols that were not overwritten".

Comment: @coolbartek memory allocators will often fill in memory with a particular pattern when in debug mode.  In relase mode you would be more likely to see random values.